# Keras ValueError in seq2seq model, "Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays"

Tags: python, arrays, keras, concatenation, lstm

I'm working with a seq2seq model for a chatbot, and when I run it I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1
>   arrays: [array([[1016,  627, 1016, ...,    0,    0,    0],
>          [ 798,  287,  422, ...,    0,    0,    0],
>          [ 777,    0,    0, ...,    0,    0,    0],
>          ...,
>          [1863,  709,  370, ...,    0, ...

I suspect it has something to do with the Concatenate layer, so I tried feeding the two items being concatenated without the extra brackets, and feeding the pair of them in brackets directly to the following Dense layer, but neither one worked. The data I'm feeding in is sequences of integers representing words that are mapped to a Word2Vec vector space by the shared Embedding layer.

```
padded_context = sequence.pad_sequences(context,maxlen=maxlen_input,padding='post',truncating='post')
padded_replies = sequence.pad_sequences(replies,maxlen=maxlen_input,padding='post',truncating='post')

input_context = Input(shape=(maxlen_input,),dtype='int32',name='input_context')
input_reply = Input(shape=(maxlen_input,),dtype='int32',name='input_reply')

LSTM_encoder = LSTM(sentence_embedding_size,init='lecun_uniform')
LSTM_decoder = LSTM(sentence_embedding_size,init='lecun_uniform')

Shared_Embedding = Embedding(output_dim=word_embedding_size, input_dim=vocab_size,weights=[embedding_mtx])

word_embedding_context = Shared_Embedding(input_context)
context_embedding = LSTM_encoder(word_embedding_context)

word_embedding_reply = Shared_Embedding(input_reply)
reply_embedding = LSTM_decoder(word_embedding_reply)

merge_layer = Concatenate(axis=1)([context_embedding,reply_embedding])
out = Dense(vocab_size/2,activation='relu')(merge_layer)
out = Dense(vocab_size,activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(input=[input_context,input_reply],output=[out])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam')

print model.summary()

model.fit(x=padded_context,y=padded_replies,batch_size=32,epochs=10)
```

I also tried chasing the error traceback through the Keras documentation but couldn't make anything of it. If it helps, here is the model summary as well:

[image]

Comment: The model you have defined has two inputs, i.e. `[input_context,input_reply]`, however you are only giving it one input array, i.e. `padded_context`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, thank you for helping me find that!